# How to solve unterminated string constant javascript error

Tags: javascript, html, struts

I am trying to pass multiple parameters in onclick function but i am getting `unterminated string constant`

```
<s:iterator value="#childMenu.menuItems" id="childs">
        <s:set var="childItemName" value="#childs.menuItemName" />
        <s:set var="childItemURL" value="#childs.menuItemUrl" />
        <sj:menuItem id="secondLevelChildMenuItem" title="%{childItemName}" onclick="javascript:showLink('%{childItemName}','%{childItemURL}');"></sj:menuItem>
        </s:iterator>
```

what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Then one of the values likely contains a single apostrophe. You should always escape values used in JS or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Dave in the comment, you likely have an unescaped single or double quote in your `childItemName` or `childItemURL` values. Take a look here for [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unterminated_string_literal).